# DUB: Create two executable files with common code base

Tags: d, dub

I need to generate two exe files that have some common source codes. What is the best way to do it with dub?

I tried to do like [image: this], but got error message about only one main function allowed.

Here is my dub.json:

```
{
    "name": "code1",
    "authors": [ "Suliman" ],
    "description": "A minimal D application.",
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2016, Suliman",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "subPackages": [
    {
        "name": "App1",
        "targetName": "App1",
        "description": "App1",
        "targetType": "executable",
        "excludedSourceFiles" : ["source/App2/*"],
        "excludedSourceFiles" : ["source/app2.d"]
    },

    {
        "name": "App2",
        "targetName": "App2",
        "description": "App2",
        "targetType": "executable",
        "excludedSourceFiles" : ["source/App1/*"],
        "excludedSourceFiles" : ["source/app1.d"]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `dub.json` will work, but you need to explicitly tell it to build one of
the subpackages with `dub build :App1` or `dub build :App2` (where `:App1` is a
shortcut for `code1:App1`).

Separate configurations may be more appropriate here:

```json
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "App1",
        "targetType": "executable",
        "mainSourceFile": "source/app1.d",
        "excludedSourceFiles": [ "source/app2.d", "source/App2/*" ],
        "targetName": "app1"
    },
    {
        "name": "App2",
        "targetType": "executable",
        "mainSourceFile": "source/app2.d",
        "excludedSourceFiles": [ "source/app1.d", "source/App1/*" ],
        "targetName": "app2"
    }
]
```

`dub build --config=App1` will produce `app1`, 
`dub build --config=App2` will produce `app2`

A plain `dub build` will default to `App1`.

Note that you need `excludedSourceFiles` so dub doesn't see a duplicate `main`.

[The docs](http://code.dlang.org/package-format?lang=sdl) recommend against
using subpackages for this purpose:

> It is also possible to define the sub packages within the root package file, but note that it is generally discouraged to put the source code of multiple sub packages into the same source folder. Doing so can lead to hidden dependencies to sub packages that haven't been explicitly stated in the "dependencies" section. These hidden dependencies can then result in build errors in conjunction with certain build modes or dependency trees that may be hard to understand.

I realized you were using `dub.json`, so I put the json format above. For
reference, here's the `dub.sdl` format I posted earlier.

```
configuration "App1" {
    targetType "executable"
    mainSourceFile "source/app1.d"
    excludedSourceFiles "source/app2.d" "source/App2/*"
    targetName "app1"
}

configuration "App2" {
    targetType "executable"
    mainSourceFile "source/app2.d"
    excludedSourceFiles "source/app1.d" "source/App1/*"
    targetName "app2"
}
```

Comment: It seems to compile always just one app at time. Is there a way co compile many targets simultaneously? (like with cmake). E.g. I have a game engine, with many different tests/demos/examples and I want to check the all (without recompiling).

Comment: Prokop, this is still a work in progress, but targetType "none" in the parent project, might be workable for you, but I'm afraid it only works for subpackages. I have not tried it myself yet. See https://github.com/dlang/dub/pull/1364 and its referenced PRs for more details